# VueJS loading SVG file depending on variable in for loop using v-html giving [object Module] instead

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, svg

I'm trying to load SVGs saved in separate files depending on the content in a loop. When the page loads, I see this:

[image]

Hey, Here's my code:

```
<div
  v-for="(rec, index) in stats"
  :key="index"
>
    <div class="iconForeground align-self-center" v-html="require(`../../../assets/svg/dashboard/attributes/${rec.icon}.svg`)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the data function, I've omitted the whole thing for brevity:

```
data() {
  return {
    stats: [{name: "Leadership", percent: "75", top: "5", icon: "leadership"}, 
            {name: "Innovation", percent: "25", icon: "genius-ideas"}] as Array<Record<string, string>>
  }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**
Here's my vue.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
      preProcessor: 'scss',
      patterns: [
        "./src/styles/global.scss"
      ]
    },
    configureWebpack: {
      module: {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2** It seems even after installing url-loader and following the advice, I still cannot load the image, here's my updated vue.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
      preProcessor: 'scss',
      patterns: [
        "./src/styles/global.scss"
      ]
    },
    configureWebpack: {
      module: {
        rules: [
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                esModule: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my html:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" :style="{marginRight: '24px'}">
    <div class="purpleDot"></div>
    <div class="iconForeground align-self-center">
       <img :src="require(`../../../assets/svg/dashboard/attributes/${rec.icon}.svg`)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use [dynamic](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) components such as this

```
<template>
  div
    v-for="(m, i) in modules"
    :key="i">
    <component :is="m.image"></component>
  </div>
</template>
```

`import PraiseIcon from "@/assets/svg/navigation-bar/Praise-Icon.svg";`

```
components: {
  'Praise-Icon': PraiseIcon
},
data() {
  return {
    modules: [
        {
          name: "Praise",
          image: "Praise-Icon",
        }
      ] as Array<Record<string, string>>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your svg loader

```
   {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
        },
```

add svg to your url-loader

```
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                esModule: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        }
```

this normally because your webpack loader settings

try set the `esModule` option in `url-loader` to `false`.

this should fix your issue.

---

you don't need to follow content below.

and another issue, even if you fixed your loader, you still can't load it.

for the image you should use `img` tag to load it.

```
<img :src=`require(...)`/>
```

`v-html` will only loads it's path string.

Comment: But I'd like to load it as an svg so I can customize it further. I don't want to load it as an image.

Comment: in your way you are not loading it as svg either, you are loading it as a string. anyway, you can just set the url-loader options to fix your issue. don't need to use img tag.

Comment: I've posted my vue.config.js, could you direct me on where I should add the properties you stated?

Comment: @Ayudh check this doc https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/

Comment: I see, xièxie :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes that I've made, I'm still unable to load the files